# String Manipulation in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, amazon-ecs

I am writing a groovy script which will return me the list of Task-Definition in AWS ECS service,
Here is the code snippet for the same

```
def p = 'aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix test'.execute() | 'jq .taskDefinitionArns[]'.execute()
p.waitFor()
print p.text
```

and the output is

```
"arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:496712345678:task-definition/test:2"
"arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:496712345678:task-definition/test:3"
```

Now I want to capture only the last part of the result, i.e **test:2**, **test:3** and so on without double quotes

How can I do that using Groovy language as I have to use it in ***Jenkins's active choice reactive parameter plugin***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
​def text = "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:496712345678:task-definition/test:2" + "\n" + "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:496712345678:task-definition/test:3"​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Try :

```
text​.split("\n")​​​​​​​​​​​​​.collect {c -> c.split("/").last()}​​​​​​
```

This  prints a list of `[test:2, test:3]`

If you want it in one line and not in an list, use:

```
text​.split("\n")​​​​​​​​​​​​​.collect {c -> c.split("/").last()}​​​​​.join(",")​
```

This prints: `test:2,test:3`

**Update**

Due to OP's comment, the answer after all should look something like:

```
def p = 'aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix test'.execute() | 'jq .taskDefinitionArns[]'.execute()
p.waitFor()
def text =  p.text
println text​.split("\n")​​​​​​​​​​​​​.collect {c -> c.split("/").last()}​​​​​​
```

Comment: `def p = 'aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix test'.execute() | 'jq .taskDefinitionArns[]'.execute()
p.split("\n").collect {c -> c.split("/").last()}.join(",")`
but I am getting the following error

`Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.UNIXProcess.split() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [
]`

Comment: In the question there is p.waitFor()  and p.text to get a text. save it in variable and then try the snippet I've provided in the answer

Comment: It worked !!!
I have got the following result

`[test:2", test:3"]
`
but I want it like

`test2
test3`

below each other

Comment: Then use: text​.split("\n")​​​​​​​​​​​​​.collect {c -> c.split("/").last()}.join("\n")

Comment: Hi, I am almost there,
my output is 
`test:1"`
`test:2"`

just need to get rid of that last `"`

Comment: I'm not sure how you've got that output, but given its a string, consider applying `.replace("\"", "")​​​​​​​` at the end

Comment: It worked, Thanks
I have added this line 

`return standardOut.tokenize("\n").collect {c -> c.replace("\"", "").split("/").last()}`

Answer (score 0):

You can split using `/` and get the last element:

```
def p = "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:496712345678:task-definition/test:2"
def result = p.split("/").last()
```

Comment: `def p = 'aws ecs list-task-definitions --family-prefix test'.execute() | 'jq .taskDefinitionArns[]'.execute()
def result = p.split("/").last()`

Getting following error

`Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.UNIXProcess.split() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [/]
`

Answer (score 0):

**Just adding another Style :**

```
String.metaClass.getMyString{-> delegate.substring(delegate.lastIndexOf("/")+1, delegate.length()-1).replace(":", "")}
println p.text.readLines()*.getMyString().join(" ")
```

Happy Learning... ! :)

Comment: yes, well it worked with normal groovy scripting but not in Jenkins UI